# Is it possible to assign a "default method" in Ruby modules or classes?

Tags: ruby

I don't know how to explain it in words, so let me show it in code:

```
module Foo
  # "default method"
  def self(string)
    "It's a #{string}"
  end

  def self.add(a, b)
    a + b
  end
end

Foo.add(10, 5)
# => 15

Foo('test')
# => It's a test
```

Is such thing possible in Ruby? thanks.

Comment: umm... I don't think it can be a module and a function at the same time...

Comment: Probably, U mean this `Foo.some_unknown_method(some_args)`  right ?

Comment: `Foo('test')` doesn't make any sense in terms of `OOPS`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but you can define method named the same way as module or class:

```
module Foo
  def self.add(a, b)
    a + b
  end
end

def Foo(string)
  "It's a #{string}"
end

Foo.add(10, 5)
# => 15

Foo('test')
# => It's a test
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I've been looking for.